# How to pass parameters into the future instance of Futurebuilder?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to pass parameters into the future instance but I encounter the "error instance member can't be accessed in an initializer" for `_getData` at `future: _getData` even though I have initialized it in initState.

```
class _DisplayListState extends State<DisplayList> {

  late Future<QuerySnapshot> _getData;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData(String value)async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('x')
        .where('a', isEqualTo: value)
        .get();
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _getData = getData(widget.value);
  }

  Widget displayList = FutureBuilder(
    future: _getData, 
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      return Container();
    },
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: displayList,
    );
  }
}
```

I remove the the parameters for `getData` thinking that I should simplify the problem first and tried `future: getData()` but I encoutered the same error.

The only way that I don't encounter the error is if I do this - `future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('x').where('a', isEqualTo: 'something').get()` for `FutureBuilder`. But this means I cannot pass parameters and I would prefer to use a function/variable for this over the long line of code.

`future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('x').where('a', isEqualTo: value).get()` where `value=widget.value` is initialized in initState will give me the same error.

Comment: just create `FutureBuilder` inside `build` method - why would you need that `Widget displayList = FutureBuilder( ...` for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method for `displayList` instead of a variable.

You can change this:

```dart
      Widget displayList = FutureBuilder(
        future: _getData, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return Container();
        },
      );
```

to this:

```dart
    Widget getDisplayList()  => FutureBuilder(
        future: _getData, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return Container();
        },
    );
```

And in the `Scaffold`'s body, use the method like this:

```dart
      body: getDisplayList()
```